# POST-Запрос и его ответ

Tags: c#, http, post

Вступление:
У РЖД есть такая программа лояльности - РЖД Бонус. Суть её в том, что за успешные поездки пассажирам полагается некий бонус. Бонус может быть зачислен на сайте РЖД - указываем необходимые данные: куда, откуда, когда, номер поезда, и т.д., жмём кнопку - отправляется запрос на сервер, после чего юзер получает автоматическое письмо с ответом, получил ли он бонус, или данные введены некорректно. 
Я хочу рулить этим процессом через своё приложение.

Сначала объявляю httpClient, и использую далее именно этот экземпляр, не создавая новые. Прохожу авторизацию на сайте, и далее пытаюсь провести пост-запрос, который вернёт мне результат. 
Все необходимые данные для запроса у меня есть. Как формируется запрос знаю (прога Fidler помогла). Но, если произвожу действия через сайт - получаю один результат - приходит письмо, если имитирую те же действия через программу - письма нет.

Кусок кода:

```
        request_string = "https://rzd-bonus.ru/privateoffice/request.html";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, request_string);

        var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("departureStationText", from),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("departureStation", from_code),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("arrivalStationText", to),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("arrivalStation", to_code),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("travelDateString", date),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("trainNumber", train_num),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ticketNumber", ticket_num),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("docType", doc_type),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("docNumber", doc_num)
         });

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(request_string, formData);
        string txt = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

В переменную txt в итоге выводится инфа по предыдущим запросам. Но именно текущий запрос почему-то всегда игнорируется. Инфа по нему добавляется только если провести запрос непосредственно с сайта.

Очень прошу помочь опытных коллег

Comment: в принципе запросы можно отсекать по типу клиента. Система видит что ваша программа не является известным браузером и игнорирует запрос. Покопайте свойства клиента, там должно быть свойство, позволяющее настроить идентификатор клиента. Это при условии что сам запрос полностью корректен

Answer (score 1):

Главный совет - прежде чем писаь httpClient проверить через фиддлер минимально необходимые параметры "эмуляции браузера". Например какие куки обязательно надо сохранять и передавать. Какие заголовки, как, например почти всегда эти:

- Connection: keep-alive
- Accept: */ *
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
  NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
  Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
- Referer: (указывается
  сайт-реферрер)
- Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language:
  ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

и только потом, когда запрос через фиддлер будет успешен - писать клиент.